# Getting System.NullReferenceException while setting value into Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, mongodb

We are using Azure B2C for Login into Our website, but in CM server we are getting below error . The Same code is working in CD server. I don't remember what i have missed in CM server (any config entry or any setting).

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 10:      
Line 11: Claim _B2CEmailAuthenticationClaim = cookieAuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(UserProfileDetails.Email)).Single();
Line 12: Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify("shailesh.kumar.sahu@e.com");
```

**In  Log File**

```
9048 07:11:07 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/contactProcessing
Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
Message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Data.Contact.ContactWorkDispatcher.TryGetNext(ContactWorkItem& workItem)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Data.Contact.ContactProcessingAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

Comment: I'm not sure but can you just do a comparison of the different config file between your CM and CD? You can use winmerge

Answer (score 2):

`Tracker.Current` really is only meant to be run on the **Content Delivery** servers and not the Content Management server. It would seem to me, you are executing code at a time where Tracker isn't available, without checking to see if Tracker is enabled.

When `Tracker` isn't available, calls like `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session...` will generate an object not found error because of `Tracker.Current = null`.

I advise, anywhere where you are executing `Tracker.Current`, that you check to see if Tracker.Current is equal to **null**.

If so, you may need to reconfigure how you are obtaining contact/interaction data by using the `ContactManager`, `ContactRepository`, or `SharedSessionManager` classes.

Comment: reconfigure :- Compare the Config files from CD ??????

Comment: No, code differently.  Your use case isn't fully thought out enough for me to provide a more quality answer. If you'd like, add some additional detail about what exactly is occurring on the CM server that is not working.